# Get data from another function

Tags: python

i have a short question, im trying to make a quiz program, however. i want a functions data to be shared across the program,

so how do i make so the ask function gen get the data from getQuestion?

```
import random

All_questions = ["whats obamas last name ","Riclug is snygg ","Are traps gay "]
questions_Right = ["care","no","no"]
points = 0
tries = 3
ListNumber = len(All_questions)

def getQuestion():
    question_number = random.randint(0, ListNumber - 1)
    right_anwser = questions_Right[question_number]
    Question = All_questions[question_number]

def ask(Question,right_anwser):
    print("The question is: ")
    anwser = input(Question+": ").casefold()
    if anwser == right_anwser:
        print("yes,", right_anwser,"was right\n")
        All_questions.remove(Question)
        questions_Right.remove(right_anwser)
    else:
        print("Sorry, but the answer was", right_anwser,"\n")
while True:
    if ListNumber == 0:
        print("Game over")
        break
    else:
        print(ListNumber)
        getQuestion()
        ask()
        print(All_questions)
```

Comment: I suggest you read the python basic tutorial, especially how functions and `return`s work. You can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

All_questions = ["whats obamas last name ","Riclug is snygg ","Are traps gay "]
questions_Right = ["care","no","no"]



def getQuestion(All_questions, questions_Right):
    question_number = random.randint(0, len(All_questions) - 1)
    
    right_answer = questions_Right[question_number]
    question = All_questions[question_number]
    
    return question, right_answer # added this to return the data



def ask():
    Question, right_answer = getQuestion(All_questions, questions_Right)
    
    answer = input(f"The question is :\n{Question} :").casefold()
    
    if answer == right_answer:
        print(f"Yes, {right_answer} was right\n")
        All_questions.remove(Question)
        questions_Right.remove(right_answer)
    
    else:
        print(f"Sorry, but the answer was {right_answer}\n")



while True:
    if len(All_questions) == 0:
        print("Game over")
        break
    else:
        ask()
```

1 - you can return the needed data by doing:

```
return question, right_answer
```

2 - since the questions list will change every round it is better to pass it to the getQuestion method instead of using the global one directly and use `len(All_questions)` to get the new length every round:

```
def getQuestion(All_questions, questions_Right)
```

3 - some advice :

- use snake casing

```
get_question
# instead of :
getQuestion
```

- don't use global variables inside functions:

```
A = 1
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
add(A, 5)

# instead of

A = 1
def add_to_A(b):
    return A + b
add_to_A(5):
```

- format your code properly and make sure that you name variables correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `return`:

```
def getQuestion():
    # ... your code
    return (Question,  rightAnswer)

#... your code

Question, rightAnswer = getQuestion()
```

And maybe try to use a dictionary, instead of an question and an answer-array. That would fit better.

I recommend you to do further reading and make some tutorials, before you go on with your quiz-game:

1. About functions:
   https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function
2. About dictionaries:
   https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary